# pandas Python 3.5.1: incremental developement using the same dataset, changed a column name but on running script, old name remains in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am parsing a Tsv (Tab separated value) file to create a pandas Dataframe using `pandas.read_csv()`. I am doing incremental changes to the Python script and executing the script each time to reflect the changes.

For example, this is how I am parsing:

```
data_column_names = ['Query','StartOffSet','EndOffset']
dataframe = pandas.read_csv("resultData.tsv", sep='\t', usecols=data_column_names
```

Now I changed the 3rd item of `data_column_names` list to `'EndOffSet'` by changing the declaration of `data_column_names`:

```
data_column_names = ['Query','StartOffSet','EndOffSet']
```

And then I am iterating over all the rows in dataframe:

```
for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():
    print(row.EndOffSet)
```

When I run this script, I get `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'EndOffSet'`. After printing the values of each row, I found that upon running the script, the dataframe still has `'EndOffset'` as the third column and not `'EndOffSet'`, which is the change I made to the scipt.

`dataframe.columns.tolist()` is showing `['Query', 'StartOffSet', 'EndOffset']`, which it shouldn't. This is the old column names. Why is the change I made to the column name not being reflected suring execution time. NO change to the Data file has been made.

How to resolve and avoid this?

N.B. I am assuming that behind the scenes, some precompiled file is being used and since the data has not changed, the precompiled files are not changed. There are no `*.pyc` files in the working directories where the code and data are stored. I logged out of the User session and then logged in again, but that didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: this `for index, row in dataframe:` shouldn't work as the iterable for a df are the columns, if you want to iterate over the rows use `iterrows`also  what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @EdChum sorry that was a typo in the question, i have edited it, I am using iterrows(). Was I not able to properly communicate the problem? What I am trying to do is getting some characteristics from a dataset that I have. While development I cam accross this problem.

Comment: does `print(row['EndOffSet'])` work? what does `df.columns.tolist()` show?

Comment: no `print(row['EndOffSet'])` also doesn't work. as far as i know, `row['EndOffSet']` and row.EndOffSet are the same thing. `dataframe.columns.tolist()` is showing `['Query', 'StartOffSet', 'EndOffset']`, which it shouldn't. This is the old name and not the new column name I have given

Comment: Well clearly this hasn't happened and you've not shown the code that demonstrates how you overwrote the column names, please edit your question with that code

Comment: I changed the declaration of the `data_column_names` variable. The current version of the code contains `data_column_names = ['Query','StartOffSet','EndOffSet']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the cause in the end. The TSV file, i.e. my data file has Header at row 0 and in the TSV file the Column names are given as 'Query' 'StartOffSet' 'EndOffset', so I have to go with those names only in my code.

Changing the column names in the `usecols` parameter of `pandas.read_csv()` is not causing any errors, but leads to different kind of erroneous behaviours during execution.